# How to iterate through images in a folder from html file with django

Tags: html, django

These are the images I want to access where the numbers of folder's names are ids

```
 img
   1 
     image1.png
     image2.png
   2
     image2.png
     image4.png
```

In views.py I send the img path to the html with this code

```
images_path = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'webapp', 'img')
# code
return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', {
        'services': services,
        'images_path': images_path
    })
```

Then in index.html I have this

```
# code
{% for service in services %}
    # code
    <div id="imagesCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner"> 
        # here I want to access to every image and show it in the carousel
        </div>
    </div>


{% endfor %}
```

Basically I want to do something like

```
{% for image in os.listdir(os.path.join(images_path, service.id)) %}
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried the above code but obviously it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to get the image paths for each service on the backend and add it to the context somehow.

For example, in views.py:

```py
images_path = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'webapp', 'img')

# ... get services from somewhere

# add the image_paths as an attribute to each service
for service in services:
    image_paths = os.listdir(os.path.join(images_path, service.id))
    setattr(service, 'image_paths', image_paths)

return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', {
    'services': services,
})
```

Then in index.html:

```
# code
{% for service in services %}
    # code
    <div id="imagesCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner"> 
        {% for image_path in image_paths %}
        <!-- whatever goes here, e.g. <img src="{{image_path}}"> -->
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this looks good. The only problem is that I can't access them with `<img src="{{image_path}}">` because index and img are in different scopes

Comment: That comment in the code there was just an example, likely an incorrect one, meant as a placeholder for whatever you want to do with the image paths once you’ve got them.